# Apache Pig: Extracting url query parameters that appear in arbitrary order

Tags: apache-pig

I have a logfile with urls that are tagged with custom Google Analytics campaign parameters (utm_source, utm_medium, utm_campaign). I need to extract the parameters from the urls and create a csv file where source, medium and campaign appear each in their own column (plus several other fields from the logfile).

This is how I started (url is the field that contains the url obviously):

```
extracted = foreach mydata GENERATE date, time, 
FLATTEN(REGEX_EXTRACT_ALL(url, '.*utm_source=(.*)&utm_medium=(.*)&utm_campaign=(.*)&.*?')) 
AS (source:CHARARRAY, medium:CHARARRAY, campaign:CHARARRAY);
```

This works, but only as long as the parameters appear in a fixed order (and are not preceeded by another parameter in the url).

So this will e.g. extract data from https://www.example.com/page.html?&utm_source=publisher&utm_medium=display&utm_campaign=standard&someotherparam but not from https://www.example.com/page.html?&utm_medium=display&utm_source=publisher&utm_campaign=standard&someotherparam. Since the parameter order is not consistent that doesn't work for me.

I have tried multiple conditions for the regexp separated by or (|) but that only ever gave me the first match. I have also tried to extract each parameter in it's own extract command and then join the data but that took ages and ended up duplicating the data.

So what would be the best (or at least a working) way to rewrite my pig command so that it will extract all three utm parameters from the urls independently from the order in which they appear ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would simply have three `REGEX_ECTRACT`:

```
... FOREACH mydata GENERATE FLATTEN(REGEX_EXTRACT(url, '.*utm_source=([^&]*)'), 1) AS (source:CHARARRAY)
...
```

Although you could probably do it with just one regex but I find this simpler and more readdable.

Comment: I have actually tried this and became for some reason convinced that didn't work (but it does). I try to remember what my problem was with that solution and if I do not remember by tomorrow I'll accept :-)